# How to compare colors in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, winforms, colors

I am doing some UI work with Vb.Net Forms application, at a place I need to match some color and change the UI according to it, at the moment I am little hanged to match the color values,

Like A_Control.Background = B_Control.Background

I have done with getting colors into string and then matching, but that is not effective in some cases, I want to implement a function, that works directly with Colors variables.

Like:

```
Dim somecolor As New Color()
somecolor = Color.FromArgb(255, 98, 153, 192)
Dim str As String = somecolor.R.ToString() + somecolor.G.ToString() + somecolor.B.ToString()
```

by doing this I can have RGB value in string and then I can convert into Integer to match with any other color, is there any  better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the simple solution that I have tested..

```
Public Function MatchColor() As Boolean
Dim cl As New Color()
'color to match
cl = Color.FromArgb(255, 98, 153, 192)
If Me.BackColor.Equals(cl) Then
    ' match the color with current forms background // you can use any
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End If
End Function
```

and function call here

```
Private Sub button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Dim match As Boolean = MatchColor()
End Sub
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a form with a timer (time) and a colordialog (cdcolor). Start with:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Public Class Form1
    Dim ccolor1 As Color = Color.(pick your color)
    Dim ccolor2 As Color = Color.(pick your color)
    Dim t = 0
```

After that you make the color change:

```
Private Sub time_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles time.Tick
        t += 1
        Select Case t
            Case 0
                Me.BackColor = ccolor1
            Case 1
                Me.BackColor = ccolor2
            Case 2
                Me.BackColor = ccolor3
            Case 3
                t = 0
        End Select
    End Sub
```